# How can I access the member variables of parent class from child class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

```
class A {
int a,b,c;
public:
A(int x, int y, int z) {
  a=x;
  b=y;
  c=z;
}
}
class B: public A {

}

int main() {
    A ob1(10, 12, 13);

    B obj;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I add 5 to each of the variables of class A object from class B object? TIA.

Comment: Make them `protected` or `public`?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @FredLarson Or allow `B` to access them via `friend`?

Comment: @MikeCAT: That would work too!

Comment: @FredLarson just want to call a function wirh obj to add 5 in each variable of ob1. is it possible?

Comment: @NabidAnzum: Class members have `private` access by default, so no, unless you change their access, provide accessors, or use `friend`.

Answer (score 0):

As the code is currently written, the 3 fields in question are `private` in `A` and thus are not accessible to `B` at all.  You would need to change `A` to make them accessible to `B`. Either by:

- making the fields themselves be `protected` or `public` instead of `private`, or at least providing `protected`/`public` accessor methods that use the fields internally, eg:

```cpp
class A {
protected:
    int a, b, c;
public:
    A(int x, int y, int z) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        c = z;
    }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void add5() {
        a += 5;
        b += 5;
        c += 5;
    }
};

int main() {
    A ob1(10, 12, 13);

    B obj;
    obj.add5();

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
class A {
    int a, b, c;
public:
    A(int x, int y, int z) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        c = z;
    }

    int geta() const { return a; }
    void seta(int value) { a = value; }

    int getb() const { return b; }
    void setb(int value) { b = value; }

    int getc() const { return c; }
    void setc(int value) { c = value; }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void add5() {
        seta(geta() + 5);
        setb(getb() + 5);
        setc(getc() + 5);
    }
};

int main() {
    A ob1(10, 12, 13);

    B obj;
    obj.add5();

    return 0;
}
```

- making `B` be a `friend` to `A`, eg:

```cpp
class A {
    int a, b, c;
public:
    A(int x, int y, int z) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        c = z;
    }

    friend class B;
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void add5() {
        a += 5;
        b += 5;
        c += 5;
    }
};

int main() {
    A ob1(10, 12, 13);

    B obj;
    obj.add5();

    return 0;
}
```